# Distance from Google Nearby Search

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3

I tried the following code for getting places from [Google Nearby Search](https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places).

```
from googleplaces import GooglePlaces, types, lang

YOUR_API_KEY = 'AIzaSyAiFpFd85eMtfbvmVNEYuNds5TEF9FjIPI'

google_places = GooglePlaces(YOUR_API_KEY)

query_result = google_places.query(
        location='London, England', keyword='Fish and Chips',
        radius=20000, types=[types.TYPE_FOOD])

if query_result.has_attributions:
    print query_result.html_attributions


for place in query_result.places:
    # Returned places from a query are place summaries.
    print place.name
    print place.geo_location
    print place.reference

    # The following method has to make a further API call.
    place.get_details()
    # Referencing any of the attributes below, prior to making a call to
    # get_details() will raise a googleplaces.GooglePlacesAttributeError.
    print place.details # A dict matching the JSON response from Google.
    print place.local_phone_number
    print place.international_phone_number
    print place.website
    print place.url
```

I got the json output of a list of places for the given location and radius. I retrieved the name, address, latitude, longitude from the json. I also need the distance of that place, but cant find it. Someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Distance Matrix API.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/)

It will return you an output like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<DistanceMatrixResponse> 
<status>OK</status> 
<origin_address>Vancouver, BC, Canada</origin_address> 
<origin_address>Seattle, État de Washington, États-Unis</origin_address> 
<destination_address>San Francisco, Californie, États-Unis</destination_address> 
<destination_address>Victoria, BC, Canada</destination_address> 
<row> 
 <element> 
  <status>OK</status> 
  <duration> 
  <value>340110</value> 
  <text>3 jours 22 heures</text> 
  </duration> 
  <distance> 
   <value>1734542</value> 
   <text>1 735 km</text> 
  </distance> 
 </element>
 ......
```

Comment: Thankyou for the reply sir. But i have looked at this. It needs a origin and a destination na?

Comment: yes. you should able to get your current address. For destination, you should able to retrieve from your google place URL. So for each of your result you retrieved from your Google Place API, you should use it as parameter as destination_address.